# How to get the Initial date of the month in DB2

Tags: stored-procedures, db2

In StoredProcedure we are passing the date like 'From date' = 2014-08-12 and 'End Date' = 2015-06-24.

I want to find like 'From Date' = 2014-08-01 and 'End Date' =2015-06-30.

Answer (score 1):

So you want to go from the beginning of whatever month is passed in as from, to the ending of whatever month is passed in as end.

Beginning of month
`last_day(fromdate) + 1 day - 1 month`

End of the month
`last_day(enddate)`

You might find it useful to create a user defined function that encapsulates the beginning of month logic.

Answer (score 0):

```
--Beginning of month
FromDate - (day(FromDate) -1) days 

--End of the month
LAST_DAY(EndDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the dates between the start and end of the current month:

```
where date between (current_date - (day(current_date) - 1) days) and (current_date + 1 month - (day(current_date)) days)
```

You will probably want to replace this current date with another date, or the minimum and maximum values from some other table or result.